# How to increment a pointer for a character in a string in x86 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to print the string "Golf" using a pointer named "character" pointing to each character in that string. When I am running the code, the only results I get is printing out the letter G four times, and I need the program to increment the character every time it runs until it completes the word. How do I dereference and then increase the pointer, so that each character will print out properly?

I do not have much experience with pointers, so any feedback or criticism is greatly appreciated!

Here's the code below:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
    wor BYTE "Golf", 0
    character BYTE PTR [wor]
    ; global variables

.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, 4
    again:
        mov al, wor
        call WriteChar
        inc character
        loop again
    call Crlf
    call WaitMsg
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What assembler is this?

Comment: You need to increment a register that you use as an offset, like `[wor + esi]`.  incrementing the byte in memory at the `character` label is totally independent from anything else your program is doing.